# I don't understand this SQL Server MIN() resultset

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this `SQL Server` query which I wrote to *find the Movie title that has the least amount of records in the `RENTAL` table*.

When run, it returns a resultset that is identical to the resultset I get from executing the sub-query by itself.

In other words, rather returning the single movie with the minimum RentalCount, it returns all movie titles and their corresponding RentalCount.

```
SELECT B.Title, MIN(B.RentalCount) AS RentalCount
FROM (
    SELECT Movie.Title, Count(*) AS RentalCount
    FROM Rental
    JOIN Dvd ON Rental.RentalID=Dvd.DvdID
    JOIN Movie ON Dvd.Movieid=movie.MovieID
    GROUP BY Movie.Title
    ) B
GROUP BY B.Title
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is correct. Your subquery returns the total count for each title on the rental table. And the result will be the same on the outer query because you have grouped them by their title also.

*follow-up question: what result do you want to achieved?*

> find the Movie title that has the least amount of records in the RENTAL table

```
SELECT Movie.Title, Count(*) AS RentalCount
FROM Rental
        JOIN Dvd ON Rental.RentalID=Dvd.DvdID
        JOIN Movie ON Dvd.Movieid=movie.MovieID
GROUP BY Movie.Title
HAVING Count(*) = 
    (
        SELECT MIN(t_count)
        FROM
        (
            SELECT Count(*) t_count
            FROM Rental
            GROUP BY Title
        ) a
    )
```

**UPDATE 1**

Thanks to **[Martin Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73226/martin-smith)** for introducing me `TOP....WITH TIES`

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES Movie.Title, Count(*) AS RentalCount
FROM Rental
        JOIN Dvd ON Rental.RentalID=Dvd.DvdID
        JOIN Movie ON Dvd.Movieid=movie.MovieID
GROUP BY Movie.Title
ORDER BY RentalCount DESC
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/acc71/4)

Comment: I took out the outer GROUP BY and B.Title and it worked. However, now I just have a number. I still want to be able to display the title of the movie as well.

Comment: @RyanMiller I don't recommend to use `TOP` for this case because there are possibilities that there are multiple title with the same lowest rental count, eg Title2 = 3, Title1 = 3, Title4 = 3..

Comment: @JohnWoo - You can use `TOP ... WITH TIES` for that.

Comment: @MartinSmith I wish I can give you `+50` on your reputation for your `TOP...WITH TIES`. I never knew it existed until now! :D

Answer (score 0):

You could have done this without a subquery

```
SELECT TOP 1 Movie.Title, Count(*) AS RentalCount
FROM Rental
JOIN Dvd ON Rental.RentalID=Dvd.DvdID
JOIN Movie ON Dvd.Movieid=movie.MovieID
GROUP BY Movie.Title
ORDER BY Count(*)
```

Comment: i was also thinking for this but what if there are records which has the same lowest rental count? only one title will show in this case

Comment: Yes, it depends on what is actually needed I believe.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for a specfic movie title then do like this:

```
SELECT Movie.Title, Count(*) AS RentalCount
    FROM Rental
    JOIN Dvd ON Rental.RentalID=Dvd.DvdID
    JOIN Movie ON Dvd.Movieid=movie.MovieID
    where Movie.Title='xyz'
    GROUP BY Movie.Title
```